# TypeError when applying a textarea's value to a variable

Tags: javascript

**JavaScript**

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="textarea" cols="100" rows="10">du hello!</textarea>
```

Comment: You should really say what exact error you get...

Comment: works for me... what browser are you using?

Comment: @Kip I'm running it on Safari and @sth it gives me the error: "TypeError: Result of expression 'document.getElementById("textarea")' [null] is not an object."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TypeError: Result of expression `'document.getElementById("textarea")' [null]` is not an object.

This error states that it couldn't find an element with the id "textarea". The result of this `getElementById` operation is therefore `null`, and you can't access `.value` on `null` because it doesn't have any properties.

The root cause of this is that no element with the id "textarea" exists at the time of searching. Either you have a typo somewhere, or your script is running at a time when the element doesn't exist (yet). If your script is in the header, you'll want to write it like this:

```
document.ready = function () {
    ... script here ...
}
```

That will delay the execution until the document is ready and all elements exist.

Comment: I checked everything and typo wasn't the problem.

I tried putting `document.ready = () { /* with my script here */ }` in the head, debugged and didn't get any kind of error, but it still didn't alert the value of the textarea. I put the script inside the `<body>` and worked.

Isn't `.ready` jQuery specific? I'm making a simple web app and I don't want to use any JS frameworks.

Comment: @Espresso No, `document.ready` is not jQuery specific, but it may be browser specific. You can try `window.onload` alternatively. You'll need to post more code, I think the obvious pitfalls have been cleared by now.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **wysiwyg editor** like **tinymce** or else.
document.getElementById("textarea").value; will not work they have there own method to get data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function test(name){
    var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    alert(textarea)
  }
</script>

<textarea id="textarea" cols="100" rows="10">du hello!</textarea>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:test('this is just testing')">Test TextArea</a>
```

Comment: i mean to say text-editor. other than you cam also check that there should be one tag with id="textarea".you can check your browser pls refer my answer after edit.